# How to generate dependencies with header files from different directories using a Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, dependencies, boost-asio, header-files

I'm trying to use the ASIO library for a networking project. My project and the ASIO header files are located in different directories. Compilation of my main.cpp (which does nothing but include **asio.hpp** and **iostream**) works just fine, but the **make depend** command yields an error saying that **asio.hpp** was not found. How might I fix this?

```
CC = g++
ASIO = -I /Users/user1/Desktop/SDK/asio-1.18.0/include
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11 ${ASIO}

SRCS = main.cpp
#SRCS = ${wildcard *.cpp}
OBJS = ${SRCS:.cpp=.o}
INCLS = ${SRCS:.cpp= main.h}

a.out: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS)

$(OBJS):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $*.cpp

depend: Makefile.dep
    $(CC) -MM $(SRCS) > Makefile.dep

Makefile.dep:
    touch Makefile.dep

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) a.out core a.exe

include Makefile.dep
```

Comment: Do you need to include CFLAGS in your depend CC command?

Comment: You must have a stale dependency in `Makefile.dep`, try zero-ing out this included file. Even though you're trying to build it, before that happens `make` will still read its current contents and attempt to resolve it. You should invest some time in investigating how automake handles this situation.

Comment: You should definitely read this: [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/). The author (Paul D. Smith) is the main maintainer of GNU make and I think you cannot find a better explanation on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so mysterious: the option describing where to find headers is here:

```
ASIO = -I /Users/user1/Desktop/SDK/asio-1.18.0/include
```

and the rule to build dependencies is here:

```
depend: Makefile.dep
        $(CC) -MM $(SRCS) > Makefile.dep
```

Notice anything missing?  The option used to find headers isn't present in that command.  Change it to:

```
depend: Makefile.dep
        $(CC) $(ASIO) -MM $(SRCS) > Makefile.dep
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help - ended up being an easy fix.